# onKey override in ControlExtension class cannot intercept camera key

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

The onKey event of my class extending from ControlExtension class is not called when Camera key is pressed. Is it a design choice or will it be coming in next releases of SDK or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is no plan to allow overriding Camera Key, in future SDK releases. Because it provides a quick access to Camera application for instant photo shoots.